# $(window).scroll event firing inconsistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Making a header that resizes after scrolling, what I have works when I scroll downwards, then fails when I scroll all the way to the top and attempt to get the header to get larger again. Sometimes it'll resize, and sometimes it won't; and it's never instant.

Here's the Code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 50) {
    $('.header').animate({
        'padding': 0
    }, 300);
} else {
    $('.header').animate({
        'padding-top': 15,
        'padding-right': 7,
        'padding-bottom': 15,
        'padding-left': 25
    }, 300);
}});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Need to understand that scroll event fires many times a second. You are telling the element to animate over and over and over

Comment: @charlietfl I can understand this, being this fired so many times. We need to set a flag for this. Check my answer. Personal Experience.

Comment: Does it work Ryan? You can comment here.. `:)`

Comment: Your answer works perfectly Praveen, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a flag for this, which checks whether the same thing has been done or not. There might be glitches in the following code, but need to tweak it in the right environment. If needed, change the first line to `true`.

```
var flag = false;
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 50) {
    if (flag) {
      $('.header').animate({
        'padding': 0
      }, 300);
      flag = false;
    }
  } else {
    if (!flag) {
      $('.header').animate({
        'padding-top': 15,
        'padding-right': 7,
        'padding-bottom': 15,
        'padding-left': 25
      }, 300);
      flag = true;
    }
  }
});
```

Setting this `flag` here, will make sure that the function gets executed only once, during its range.